# php multi thread on linux centos php 5.6

Tags: php, linux, centos

someone knows if is there a way to use php multi thread on php 5.6, if yes where can i found a tutorial step by step to do it?

I need some solution for multi thread, currently i'm using multi curl to do it, but i think it's not right way to do it, using curl to access script on same server.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: Love when I am typing out an answer and then the question is closed.

Comment: i don't think it's duplicated ... i'm asking about php 5.6 ... not php 5.7.

Comment: I am not going to retype out my diatribe, but the basic idea is there is a built in pthreads library in PHP and you probably want to use Gearman and not threads.  http://php.net/manual/en/book.gearman.php